# Bad character code (-1) when i use monospace

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, typewriter

I am working with mako, python and latex, and I want to have a monospaced font in my document! I am using this commands:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{inconsolata}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Source LaTex File: /tmp/tmpPBrCPK/1394108320.270.tex
Run count: 1
Bad character code (-1).:77:{-17253.39}<!>
Bad character code (-1).:77:{-17253.39}<!>
Bad character code (-1).:77:{-17253.39}<!>
Bad character code (-1).:86:{IIBB BS AS}<!>
Bad character code (-1).:90:{Retencion ing br}<!>
Bad character code (-1).:94:{Percepciones II.BB. BSAS}<!>
```

I tried with `\endlinechar=98` and `\endlinechar=13`, in the second case I get the same error, in the first I get

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.:32:<!>
Undefined control sequence.:13:\else<!>
Undefined control sequence.:20:\fi<!>
Undefined control sequence.:24:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:14:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:14:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:14:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:55:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:51:\endinput<!>
Undefined control sequence.:39:\NR@showkeysfalse<!>
```

Any ideas? :\

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I tried a minimal document with that snippet of code and got no error. Can you show an example that goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks! The document is not static! I am generating it with python-mako. The problem is when I have a newline! :\

Comment: Try showing an instance of a generated (small) document.